# Loose, tea leaves on Shabbes

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, borer-separating

Is there an issue with using loose, tea leaves on Shabbes (assuming we use kos shlishi, etc)-- does putting loose-leaf tea into a spoon like the one attached in the picture an issue of borer or considered cooking? [image: see the spoon below] Is there any other issue with using this on Shabbes?

Comment: Cooking maybe - there are different opinions about it, see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9723/where-does-the-concept-of-a-kli-shlishi-come-from). Also, welcome to Mi Yodeya and remember that any answers here should not be taken as authoritative - rather take the information as background to ask your own Rabbi if you can do this on Shabbos.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Star-K article](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-thirst-tea.htm), no:

> Since many people enjoy their tea mainly on Shabbos, it would be
>   appropriate to briefly mention the do’s and don’ts of tea preparation
>   on Shabbos. One should not use tea/herbal bags or loose teas on
>   Shabbos. This is because tea is part of that group of foods known as
>   kaley habishul, or easily cooked foods. These foods are considered so
>   sensitive to heat since they will cook in circumstances that other
>   foods will not.
>
> Therefore, the only way to enjoy tea on Shabbos is to prepare tea
>   essence before Shabbos. The common practice is to make a very strong
>   cup of tea before Shabbos by using several bags and pouring boiling
>   water over them. It is preferable to also remove the bags before
>   Shabbos. This essence can now be added to a cup of hot water (kli
>   sheini) on Shabbos. The preferred method, however, according to Rabbi
>   Moshe Heinemann, shlita, Rabbinic Administrator of the Star-K, is to
>   place several bags into a pot of water and actually boil them up on
>   the fire before Shabbos. This essence, minus the bags, can be stored
>   in a cup and added to hot water.
>
> Alternatively, you may want to use instant tea on Shabbos. When using
>   instant tea, or coffee, the preferred method is to add the tea to the
>   hot water (kli sheini) and not vice versa.

See the footnotes in that article for sources.

I listed just one source. There are others that permit making tea using tea bags, and probably even using the loose tea in a cup.

However, I found no opinion that allowed use of the tea spoon as this is a special tool designated for straining, which is similar to the melacha of "borer".

Comment: There are [other authoritative opinions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20712/2) that permit the use of tea bags under the right circumstances.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Aware of that. That's why I started my post with "According to..."

Comment: @IsaacMoses Actually, most of those sources do not discusses tea bags. They discuss tea.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I stand corrected. My point, though, was that they stand in contradistinction to the Star-K position, which completely forbids the use of tea leaves, regardless of packaging.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Correct, though note that post was seeking out only lenient positions. The stringent position has more than enough names on its side.

Comment: "However, I found no opinion that allowed use of the tea spoon as this is a special tool...": did you find any forbidding it?

Comment: @msh210 asks a good question, since the same can be said of the tea bag. If you take the same precautions with a tea infuser (like this spoon design) as one would with a tea bag, how would it be any more problematic?