# Should we prevent a chumra in the laws of Shabbos that exceeds the normal understanding?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, cooking-bishul, stringency-chumrah

The *halacha* is that generally a *keli shelishi* does not cause *bishul*.

The Chazon Ish says that a  *keli shelishi* (or revii) above *yad soledes bo* does cook those things that are *kalei habishul*.

A [shiur by Rav Yosef Zvi Rimon](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/cookshabbat/06cookshabbat.htm) explains the lenient view

> Rashi (Shabbos 39a, s.v. De-sharei) explains that since we are not
>   accustomed to cook in the sun there is no prohibition of *bishul* in
>   the sun.
>
> For our issue, it may be that the focus of the distinction between
>   *keli [sheini]* and *keli shelishi* is the common custom.  Most foods we cook in a *keli rishon*; some foods, such as tea, coffee, baby
>   formula, etc., are commonly cooked in a *keli [sheini]*; while in a
>   *keli shelishi*, one is not accustomed to cook at all.  Naturally, we may say that even if on a practical level the foods that would cook in
>   a *keli [sheini]* would also cook in a *keli shelishi*, there is no
>   prohibition to cook them in a *keli shelishi*, because this is not
>   *derekh bishul*, and it does not fall within the boundaries of the melakha.

So here we see that to transgress the issur of *bishul* on Shabbos, it is critical that the process is *derekh bishul* even though the food may be cooked in the *keli shelishi*. (I mean that the constitution of the food may be changed by being immersed in a  *keli shelishi* which can easily be well over *yad soledes bo*.) Or to put it in other words, *bishul* is not cooking.

Someone observed cooking going on in a *keli shelishi* and wants to be extra strict and will not add anything to a *keli shelishi* which is above *yad soledes bo*.

How should we view such conduct? Is he inventing his own religion and should be convinced to abandon this view or is there room to look more kindly at his conduct?

Comment: If the person is being strict like the chazon ish then what's the problem?

Comment: The Chazon Ish restricts the chumra to the kalei habishul; this person will not add anything to a keli above yad soledes bo.

Comment: How do you know what's not kalei habishul?

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe he's asking about those things we know aren't kalei habishul, can a person be machmir on that as well.

Comment: Thanks @robev . I have another thought too. The person in the question doesn't accept the idea of *derekh bishul*. So is his chumra legitimate?

Comment: This is getting very specific. Usually a chumra could mean being strict for a minority opinion/case out of doubt, or being strict on something completely permitted as a fence.  It's getting hard to tell whether your case is one of those or not

Comment: My understanding of why there are acharonim who don't allow cooking in a keli shelishi wouldn't depend on ease of bishul, The phrase "keli shelishi" doesn't appear in the classic literature, (I am not sure you can find it at all until the 20th cent. Aside from the Yerei'm saying it's no different lehalakhah.). Saying that it's different in halakhah than a keli sheini, ie that "keli sheini" isn't just in contrast to a keli rishon, needs proving.

Comment: @micha indeed https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9723/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R. Eliezer of Metz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Samuel) in [Yereim 274](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yereim.274.10?lang=bi) writes explicitly that one should not put any food in a *keli sheni* nor in a *keli shelishi* (if they are at the temperature of *yad soledet bo*) as we do not know which types of food would cook in such a vessel:

> יזהר אדם שלא להכניס בשבת שום דבר בכלי שני **ואף בכלי שלישי** שהיד סולדת בו שאין אנו בקיאים בדברים רבים וקשים מי הוא מתבשל בכלי שני ומי הוא שאינו מתבשל

It would seem that taking this opinion into account is a classic case of a *chumra* attempting to satisfy minority opinions.