# Can a Kli Sheini be built onto a Kli Rishon?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul

If I want to use use hot water from my coffee urn on Shabbat (as I understand it, the urn is a kli rishon) to make instant coffee, I pour it into a separate cup and pour from there into the cup that I intend to drink from. While there might be all sorts of halachic intricacies which would change this process, I'd like to start this hypothetical with those parameters.

Does the kli sheini into which I pour the hot water have to be separate from the kli rishon? Does it have to have a certain size or shape?

Could I attach a small receptacle with a secondary spigot to the spigot on the urn so that I can consider that "way station" to be a kli sheini (as it is not heated by the urn) and I can open the secondary spigot and pour from there into my coffee cup? Would the intermediary have to be of a certain size, or shape? Would I have to wait a period before emptying it into my coffee cup?

[image]

Comment: There is a big discussion if hot water from your sink is kli rishon from the boiler downstairs or not. That'll be the best place to start

Comment: I saw a question that asked about pipes and there seemed to be some idea that pipes, themselves, aren't keilim (though I don't know if that is accurate, or what is a "pipe" vs anything else.) My original question included the possibility of a longer outflow pipe from the spigot but since I don't know the laws of pipes as keilim, I limited it to an actual kli, whatever that is.

Comment: Great graphics.

Comment: This sounds a bit like the lamp with an eggshell-like oil resevoir we read about every week in Bameh Madlikin.

Comment: Out of interest (and tangential to your question here) is there a reason you won't add the instant coffee directly to the hot water in your kli sheni?

Comment: Let's say that hypothetically, I hold that it should be made in a kli shlishi https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10010/1362 sourced here https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/163324/jewish/Keli-Rishon-Sheini-and-Shlishi.htm 3:6 g